# Big Query and Google Adwords (Ads): Country label

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I'm trying to find the corresponding label for the column **CountryCriteriaId**, the column is coming from **p_GeoStats_***.

The schema description says that I can find the label in LocationCriterionService but as far I understand that's a Google Adwords API function rather a table in Big Query.

Do you know where can I find the labels inside the Adwords schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The labels are not inside BigQuery, they are located in what's called GeoTargets in the Adwords API.

Adwords provide a CSV with all the IDs in the following [link](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geotargeting)